# GWD with angular 2+ - issue with data binding

Tags: google-web-designer

```
        gwd.auto_AboutEventMouseout = function(event) {
              // GWD Predefined Function
              gwd.actions.events.setInlineStyle('aboutEvent', 'border-bottom: none;');
              document.getElementById('onLoadData').style.visibility = 'visible';
            };
```

This is gwd generated code when I hover over -

```
             <li class="gwd-span-1anh" id="aboutEvent"><a>ABOUT</a>
```

So by any ways can we make a two way data binding or  *ngFor for array iteration.